# Display Data Conditionally in Laravel View

Tags: database, laravel, if-statement, laravel-blade

I'm trying to get the year from my database and check if it's 2018. If it is then the view should display all books released in 2018.

**Controller**

```php
<?php

public function getYear(){
    $year = Book::all();

    return view('/pages/trending', compact('year'));
}
```

**View**

```
@foreach ($year as $y)
    @if($y == '2018')
        <td>{{ $y->year }}</td>
    @endif
@endforeach
```

All I am getting is that the variable year is not defined.

Comment: is this a blade view? if so the correct syntax is dot notation `view('pages.trending'...`

Comment: it does the job both ways..my problem is that it says that year is indefined

Comment: can you post your route code and what endpoint you are hitting in your browser?

Comment: Thank you. I had a problem in the router. God bless you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public function getYear(){
  $data['year'] = Book::where('year',2018)->get();
  return view('pages.trending',$data);
}
```

On your view file

```
@foreach ($year as $y)
  <td>{{ $y->year }}</td>
@endforeach
```

**Hope this will help you**

Comment: still says the year is undefined

Comment: Please put the full error message . Then i can understand what will be missing

Comment: Undefined variable: year (View: C:\Users\Angel\Desktop\WEB3\WEB3GIT\web3\website\resources\views\pages\trending.blade.php)

Comment: Use return view('pages.trending',$data); instead of return view('/pages/trending',$data);

Comment: still the same result

Comment: I think you missing something. It should work smoothly.

Comment: It was the router. I managed to find the problem. Thank you very much.

Comment: Welcome Dear . Cheer